# Parse Unity SDK does not work in an Android build

Tags: android, parse-platform, unity-game-engine, android-manifest

I use Parse Unity SDK as a solution for cloud storing of all the relevant gameplay statistics. The SDK works perfectly well in the Unity editor. However, when the project is built for Android and deployed on a device, not a single piece of functionality seems to be working - a user can't sign up, log in or place any kind of data into the Parse cloud.

I have tested this from within a simple project, to avoid possible 3rd party plugin conflicts, but the result was the same.

The AndroidManifest.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.toybox.parsetest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
  <permission android:protectionLevel="signature" android:name="com.toybox.parsetest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.toybox.parsetest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

  <application android:label="ParseTest" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon">
    <activity android:name=".UnityPlayerActivity">
      <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"     />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="com.toybox.parsetest" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.parse.ParsePushService" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: there is not any problem in manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to follow this official bug thread for the issue...
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1623483557935932/

EDIT : At the bottom of the thread the developer has posted a package, which seems to have some other files and a manifest in the Plugins/Android folder. It seems you need to make sure you keep these files, and it will work.

You can download the package from 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/oc0orevllrf1ylm/Fixed-Parse-Unity-Android-Bug-1.5.2.zip?dl=0